# Attempting to access SOAP Service from Silverlight App, clientaccesspolicy.xml, crossdomain.xml

Tags: web-services, soap, fiddler, crossdomain.xml, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I am getting the dreaded "attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place" error when attempting to call a soap service. When I look at fiddler, it says

2| 404 | HTTP | THIS.ISTHEURLTOTHESERVICE.COM | /clientaccesspolicy.xml |

I am trying to understand, does this mean the I am missing the clientaccesspolicy.xml file or that the server hosting the service is missing this file? I have tried adding it to my project in many different places, also added it to c://inetpub/wwwroot but still getting the error.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Also I am running from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the clientaccesspolicy.xml file isn't getting served from the URL that you see in Fiddler. It's possible that you haven't configured IIS to serve XML files; when you haven't done that IIS will return a 404 when asked to serve such a file.